# Prorating Memberships and Cividiscount

Tags: civimember, cividiscount

CiviCRM is prorating memberships and I do not think I have setup any feature for prorating the cost of the membership. It appears to show up when I apply a discount code. For example this outrageous example.  See:

[image]

I checked and there are no CiviCRM errors, Apache error, and JS logs. Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 2):

The issue was the Membership Extra module. I have not dug into a specific component. We had not configured it but turned it on. Turning it off fixed the problem.